# Glue load job not retaining default column value in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have a Glue job that loads a CSV from S3 into a redshift table. There is 1 column (updated_date) which is not mapped. Default value for that column is set to current_timestamp in UTC. But each time the Glue job runs, this updated_date column is null.

I tried removing updated_dt from Glue metadata table. I tried removing updated_dt from SelectFields.apply() in Glue script.

When I do a normal insert statement in Redshift without using updated_dt column, default current_timestamp() value is inserted for those rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem. AWS support told me to convert the Glue DynamicFrame into a Spark DataFrame and use the Spark writer to load data into Redshift:

```
SparkDF = GlueDynFrame.toDF()

SparkDF.write.format('jdbc').options(
        url = ‘<‘JDBC url>’,
        dbtable=‘<schema>.<table>’,
        user=‘<username>’,
        password=‘<password>’).mode(‘append’).save()
```

Me on the other hand handled the problem by either dropping and creating the target table using preactions or just use some update to set the default values in the postactions.